# Accessing the spreadsheet using access token in R using googlesheets4

Tags: r, google-sheets-api, googlesheets4

I'm trying to access the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qS66SgO6Uc958WTY1_2I7zN58MxtleLN5PbadhjIBqg/edit?usp=sharing) using oAuth 2.0 in R.

I have generated the access token.

I am not clear of how to retrieve the data from the above mentioned sheet.

I have tried to access the data using this piece of code

```
sampleData <- GET("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1qS66SgO6Uc958WTY1_2I7zN58MxtleLN5PbadhjIBqg",
                          add_headers("Authorization" = new_access_token))

    data_list <- content(sampleData, "parsed")
```

Can anyone provide me a way to proceed further?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the sheet name to the end e.g

```
/values/Sheet1
```

This will get you the entire sheet. To get details of a range include *A1* notation

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId/values/Sheet1!A1:D5
```